# root.after causes Global error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have been playing with TkInter, but I am having issues getting it to quit.

I can get the text to display:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import BasePlugin
import os, sys
import time
from Tkinter import *


class dis(BasePlugin):

def execute(self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies):
    mseg = str('%s - %s' % (msg, unit))
    root = Tk()
    text = Text(root, wrap = 'word', bg= 'red', font= 'times 30 bold')
    text.insert(INSERT, msg)
    text.pack()
    root.title('Pager Printer Display')
    root.after(6000, _close)
    root.mainloop(0)


    PLUGIN = dis
```

But now I need it to close after say 7 minutes.

so I've tired adding

```
 def _close():
        root.destroy()
```

to the end, start, and middle but get an error of

```
Global name _close is undefined
```

e.g

```
class dis(BasePlugin):
    def _close():
        root.destroy()

    def execute(self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies):
        mseg = str('%s - %s' % (msg, unit))
        root = Tk()
        text = Text(root, wrap = 'word', bg= 'red', font= 'times 30 bold')
        text.insert(INSERT, msg)
        text.pack()
        root.title('Pager Printer Display')
        root.after(6000, _close)
        root.mainloop(0)

PLUGIN = dis
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` is defined as a local variable. To make it accessible in another method, you should make it as an instance attribute. Also don't forget to declare `_close` as an instance variable.

```
class dis(BasePlugin):

    def _close(self):
        self.root.destroy()

    def execute(self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies):
        mseg = str('%s - %s' % (msg, unit))
        self.root = Tk()
        text = Text(self.root, wrap = 'word', bg= 'red', font= 'times 30 bold')
        text.insert(INSERT, msg)
        text.pack()
        self.root.title('Pager Printer Display')
        self.root.after(6000, self._close)
        self.root.mainloop(0)
```

Another, simpler way is simply pass `root.destroy` as a callback.

```
class dis(BasePlugin):

    def execute(self, msg, unit, address, when, printer, print_copies):
        mseg = str('%s - %s' % (msg, unit))
        root = Tk()
        text = Text(root, wrap = 'word', bg= 'red', font= 'times 30 bold')
        text.insert(INSERT, msg)
        text.pack()
        root.title('Pager Printer Display')
        root.after(6000, root.destroy)
        root.mainloop(0)
```

Comment: Cheers bottom one worked a treat. I swear I had tried that but I could have been too frustrated by it :).